# Move an object based on XML/TXT file

Tags: c#, unity

Let's think I have an file which looks like this:

```
0 1 2  3
4 5 6  7
8 9 10 11
```

I want to create a move from this file. For every 1s(mentioned in the file) I want to move the object.

Is this possible to do or there is already scripts/implementations which can be used?

Suppose I have an xml file which looks like this

```
<Box>
<Time>0.02</Time>
<Distance>0,7.889,0</Distance>
<Time>0.02</Time>
<Distance>0,7.885,0</Distance>
<Time>0.02</Time>
<Distance>0,7.887,0</Distance>
<Time>0.02</Time>
<Distance>0,7.885,0</Distance>
</Box>
```

I want to move the object based on the distance specified in the xml sheet.We have a timer running shown in GUI Text.At the time interval shown in the xml the object should move to the certain distance shown in the xml.How can I do this?Please help me out in hard coding this.

Comment: This question is really confusing. What do you mean by "creating a move"? (Do you mean an animation?) Why do you have multiple time and distance entries? What distances do the distances represent?

Comment: Are you asking for help parsing the files or moving the GameObjects?

Comment: Please take more care in asking clear, on topic questions. You've had a number of questions closed. Please review the [help] before asking further questions, thanks.

Comment: @Anko  : moving an object(.fbx) by reading the data from the xml.I mean according the distance value specified in the xml the object should move

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Unity you can load any text file with Resources.Load() like this:

```
string text = (Resources.Load("NameOfTextAsset") as TextAsset).text;
```

After that you can use any standard C# method to split the string to parts, and Convert.ToInt32() to parse the integer from the splitted up string.

```
foreach(string part in text.Split(' ')) {
    int number = Convert.ToInt32(part);
    Debug.Log("Number: " + number);
}
```

Read more about this very basic C# stuff:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextAsset.html

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextAsset.html

http://www.dotnetperls.com/split

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx

Comment: Just to add too Lasse's answer, ensure you have a folder named "Resources" in your assets folder so the Resources.Load method will work.

Comment: @Lasse   How can do the read a data from xml file and move an object according to that value

Comment: If you don't know how to move an object with arbitrary values then maybe you should look that up through google... You essentially have two questions here. How can I read a text file and how can I move an object... Break it down into simple steps if you are having trouble and google each problem.